# URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused> Python

Tags: python, suds

I have a simple suds webservice client that has been working fine for sometime. I am however, now getting  "urllib2.URLError: " whenever i run it. Note that i can ping the remote host successfully and can also telnet on the remote host port. What are some of the things i can check to troubleshoot this? Below is my code snippet:

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.wsse import *
security = Security()
token = UsernameToken('user', 'pass')
token.setnonce()
token.setcreated()
security.tokens.append(token)

def func():
    someVar = '2222222'
    try:
        url ='http://IP:Port/SomeWebServices/service?wsdl'
        client = Client(url)
        return client.service.SomeMeth(someVat)
    except Exception,x:
        raise x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    response = func()
    print response['responseCode']
    print response['balance']
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can try:

```
    url ="your?wsdl"

    client = Client(url,cache=None)

    client.set_options(location=url)  // new line

    return client.service.SomeMeth(someVat)
```

Comment: @user3473526. I didn't answer for your question. I just edited this answer.

Comment: @EdmundChi kudos to you

Comment: @user3473526 I just do my best.